# html/css: How to prevent railing / locking to direction on touch [Horizontal scroll areas embedded in vertical scroll area]

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have a page that has multiple x-only scrollable rows embedded in a y-only scrollable page.

[image: Example]

I seem to only be able to scroll one area at a time. Which can be quite annoying, if the user wants to scroll down, but the algorithm thinks he wants to scroll right, he has to lift the finger and try again until he manages to get it right.

Q: Is there a way to prevent this railing and make up/down always scroll the outer scroll view, while left/right always scroll the row the finger is over?